# Do I have to ignore the concept of global module state with Immutable JS?

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

I have just stumbled upon Immutable JS and I believe it looks like a very interesting library for reducing the possibility of bugs due to programmer error/accidental mutation as well as the performance optimisations it offers, however I am struggling to understand how I can keep track of state within a module.

For example, if I had a socket.io server running that supported multiple streams, I would usually have two variables in the global context of that module to track connected clients and current available streams:

```
var clients = []
var streams = []
```

If a user was to connect, I could simply use `.push` in socket ios `io.on("connection")` event listener and I could rest assured that my client state would now contain the newly joined socket.

In Immutable JS, I have an object global to the module which now looks like:

```
var state = Immutable.Map({
    clients : Immutable.List.of(),
    streams : Immutable.List.of()
})
```

Inside of socket io's connection handler, how can I update the global state?  I believe Immutable JS works like this, so maintaining application state doesn't even seem possible (because of the way I am currently thinking about it)

```
// Define the Immutable array, this remains constant throughout the application
var state = Immutable.Map({
    clients : Immutable.List.of(),
    streams : Immutable.List.of()
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

     console.log(state.clients)    

     // I would like to update the state of clients here, but I believe that 
     // I am only able to make a local copy within the context of the current
     // scope, I would then lose access to this on the next socket joining?

     var clientsArray = state.clients
     clientsArray.push(socket)
     state.set("clients", clientsArray)

     console.log(state.clients)
})
```

From my understanding, I believe that the console.log statements, on two clients connecting would results in the following output:

```
// First client connects
[]
[ { socket object } ]

// Second client connects
[]
[ { socket object } ]
```

Is it possible for me to update the object so that I would get

```
[ { socket object }, { socket object } ]
```

Or am I going to need to stick to using global mutable state?   The only reason I ask this question, is because when I have used react in the past, you are able to update component state in a method and then use that new state elsewhere in a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing a simple assignment. As you are using immutable, any update operation, like `set`, results in a brand new object being created. In your case the following code `state.set("clients", clientsArray)` doesn't change the global state, but returns a new instance with the modified `clients` List.
To fix this, you need to simply update the global state with the result of the call, like so -

`state = state.set("clients", clientsArray);`

Or you could rewrite this all in one shot -

`state = state.set("clients", state.get("clients").push(socket));`

Hope this helps!

As a rule of thumb, remember that you always need to have an assignment whenever you are invoking a method which changes/mutates the immutable.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed thank you. I knew that a new copy was returned I just wasn't sure if I could then reset the global.